# Meta keywords and google

Tags: seo, search-engine, keyword, adsense

I recall an article (by a Google employee) that says keywords are obsolete now regarding SEO.  This may be true, but is it possible that meta keywords can determine relevancy of AdSense ads?  Another words, should meta keywords be ignored or used?

Comment: Google does not read meta keywords. fullstop.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, ignore the keyword meta tag.

Neither Google Crawler nor Google AdSense is using the meta keywords, because they are completly useless, create good content, use headers and structured content, and you will be good.

Answer (score 0):

"At least for Google's web search results currently (September 2009), the answer is no. Google doesn't use the "keywords" meta tag in our web search ranking."

Read this: [Google does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hu/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Google employee you are thinking of is Matt Cutts, he said Google doesn't factor in meta keywords into their search algorithm. You can completely ignore them.

Source: [7 Common SEO Mistakes To Avoid](http://codecrater.com/blog/7-common-seo-mistakes-avoid/)

codecrater.com/blog/7-common-seo-mistakes-avoid/

Answer (score 0):

> Even though search engines yahoo and bing use this tag as a less
>   significant one in ranking purposes, 
>   **It's better to ignore meta keywords tag.**

Answer (score 0):

Meta keywords doesn't have any impact on SEO of a website or blog but I recommend to use it as it doesn't have any disadvantage in using it. I am using meta keywords on each post published by me on my blog and it leads to generate traffic.

Secondly, Google had announced that they will not use meta keywords or meta tags to rank a blog in search results. But it doesn't told that it is restricted to use meta keywords.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).